# Continous Parent and Discrete Child Conditional with Observed Data in PyMC

Tags: probability, pymc

I am new to PyMC and trying to set up the simple conditional probability model: `P(has_diabetes|bmi, race)`.  Race can take on 5 discrete values encoded as 0-4 and BMI can take on a non-zero positive real number.  So far I have the parent variables setup like this:

```
p_race = [0.009149232914923292,
          0.15656903765690378,
          0.019637377963737795,
          0.013947001394700141,
          0.800697350069735]
race = pymc.Categorical('race', p_race)

bmi_alpha = pymc.Exponential('bmi_alpha', 1)
bmi_beta = pymc.Exponential('bmi_beta', 1)
bmi = pymc.Gamma('bmi', bmi_alpha, bmi_beta, value=bmis, observed=True)
```

I have observed data that looks like:

> | bmi | race | has_diabetes |
>   |      21.7 |    1 |            0 |
>   |      45.3 |    4 |            1 |
>   |      18.9 |    2 |            0 |
>   |      26.6 |    0 |            0 |
>   |      35.1 |    4 |            0 |

I am attempting to model `has_diabetes` as:

```
has_diabetes = pymc.Bernoulli('has_diabetes', p_diabetes, value=data, observed=True)
```

My problem is that I am not sure how to construct the `p_diabetes` function since it is dependent on the values of `race` and and the continuous value of `bmi`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to construct a deterministic function that generates `p_diabetes` as a function of your predictors. The safest way to do this is via a logit-linear transformation. For example:

```py
intercept = pymc.Normal('intercept', 0, 0.01, value=0)
beta_race = pymc.Normal('beta_race', 0, 0.01, value=np.zeros(4))
beta_bmi = pymc.Normal('beta_bmi', 0, 0.01, value=0)

@pymc.deterministic
def p_diabetes(b0=intercept, b1=beta_race, b2=beta_bmi):

    # Prepend a zero for baseline
    b1 = np.append(0, b1)

    # Logit-linear model
    return pymc.invlogit(b0 + b1[race] + b2*bmi)
```

I would make the baseline race be the largest group (it is assumed to be index 0 in this example).

Actually, its not clear what the first part of the model above is for, specifically, why you are building models for the predictors, but perhaps I am missing something.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I do have a quick question about the logit-linear model.  Why have a baseline race instead of having the race linear factor be sampled from a normal, i.e. have  `beta_race = pymc.Normal('beta_race', 0, 0.01, value=np.zeros(5))`

Comment: That is an alternative parameterization. Its true, you can simply have a separate intercept for each race, and this works well if the counts within each racial group are similar. Often, one race is considerably more frequent than others, in which case my parameterization tends to work better.